# How get the configs of a xcodeproj with command line (using xcodebuild)

Tags: xcode, command-line, xcode4, xcodebuild

I will create a build script with xcodebuild command.

But, I want get the config of my project, like `PROJECT_DIR` and use it for next action. Or better, I only want to know where the .app will be create.

Any suggest or I will have to read the internal xcodeproj files to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
In Product > Edit Scheme you can add a script to the "post-action" part of the dropdown menu, check "provide build settings from program" and export the $(BUILD_PRODUCTS_DIR) variable (or write it to a file, whatever).

I did not get the meaning of your question at first, sorry.

Old stuff:
You can right-click on the target and select "show in Finder" to know where it is going to be built.

If you don't like the location (default is a long path) you can change the preferences of Xcode to save the DerivedData-Folder directly in the project-folder. Then the path will be something like $(projectfolder)/DerivedData/Build/Product/program.

I assume you are using Xcode4.

Comment: No, I know were it is build, but I want to know it in source code. Because if I change something in the project, my script can get it and use the new location.